# Read URL request to string C# console aplication

Tags: c#, server, console-application

I am trying to read url request that was sent via browser to my server. So basicly if I type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ as my URL, server will respond and send a picture that is going to be displayed properly. Now I am trying to get the URL into string so if for example I type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/1234 I would be able to get 1234 out of my url string and then resize, rotate,.. my picture based on the input and display it. I tried with `string my_url = listen.GetContext().toString();` but I am not getting URL that I've entered.

My code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            HttpListener listen = new HttpListener();
            string url = "http://localhost";
            string port = "";
            Console.Write("Nastavite port:");
            port = Console.ReadLine();
            url = url + ":" + port + "/geoserver/";
            listen.Prefixes.Add(url);

            try
            {
                listen.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ta port je zaseden");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cakam...");
                HttpListenerContext kontekst = listen.GetContext();



                string msg = "hello world";
              //  kontekst.Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(msg);
                kontekst.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;


                using (Stream stream = kontekst.Response.OutputStream)
                using (Image image = Image.FromFile("jpg.png"))
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    writer.WriteLine($"<html><img src=\"data: image / png; base64, {base64} \"></html>");
                } 

                Console.WriteLine("Sporočilo poslano");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are rolling your own web server?

Comment: I would like to run it on my local network and learn few things with .TIFF pictures in near future. Trying to build like "google maps" application but not that advanced obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the URI from [`kontekst.Request.Url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.url?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpListenerRequest_Url) and parse out that value yourself to decide what you need to do.